# When we can permute between the integral and convex hull?

Tags: convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is there a relation between the following expressions?

$$\operatorname{conv}\left(\int_{0}^{t} f(s,x)ds  :x \in A  \right) $$ and $$\int_{0}^{t} \operatorname{conv}(f(s,x):x \in A)\ ds $$
where $A$ is a bounded set and $\operatorname{conv}(A)$ is the convex hull of a set $A$.

Comment: I don't get the notation. $A$ is a bounded set, presumably in ${\bf R}^n$ for some $n$, so what is $f(A)$? It would have to be some set, but how do you integrate a set?

Comment: I meant by  $f(A)$ the image of the set A under the function (or multifunction f)  and the integral of $f(A)$ is given by the following expression $$\{ \int f(x) d\mu : x\in A \}  $$

Comment: Is that the same as $\int_Af(x)\,dx$? If not, then over what set are you integrating?

Comment: your questions helped me to clear my mind, the good expression that I was looking for is $$\{ \int f(t,x)dt : x \in A \} $$ I will edit my question

Comment: I still don't get it. Where does $A$ live? Where does $t$ live? Where does $f(t,A)$ live? What set are you integrating over? What does it mean to integrate the convex hull? Maybe you could give an example of the kind of set $A$ and the kind of function $f$ and the kind of integral you have in mind. Maybe if you calculated one example, you'd either have your answer, or you'd decide your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: you can take $t \in \[a,b\]  $ so the integral is Riemann integral from a to b, I'm not integrating a convex hull but  $$\operatorname{conv}\left(\int f(t,A)\,dt\right)$$ means the convex hull of set $ \( \int f(t,x) dt  : x \in A) $ and A is any bounded sets. My question :" could we permute between the convex hull and the integral as we can do with integral and limits or sums under some conditions

Comment: You still haven't told me where $A$ lives or where $f(t,x)$ lives, and you *are* integrating a convex hull when you bring the "conv" inside the integral.

Comment: OK, so, what is $N$?

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, which mapping satisfies that inclusion

Comment: In other word, for a mapping $T:A \rightarrow A$ where $A$ is a subset of a Banach space $X$ when do we have
$$conv(TA) \subseteq T(convA)$$

Comment: So, the question isn't about integration after all? Maybe you should edit the question, so it asks what you really want to ask. Anyway, doesn't every linear map work? Take two points $a,b$ in $A$, the convex hull will include the line segment joining them, and $T$ will take that to a line segment joining $T(a)$ and $T(b)$, which is the same as the convex hull of $T(a)$ and $T(b)$.

Comment: And since the integral is a linear map so it still true if N represent an integral, right ?!

Comment: I guess so, if my argument is correct. Although I'm still not sure how you integrate a convex hull.

Comment: I think it is true not only for linear maps but also for convex maps, thank you  for your time and patience